# Android App battery consumption

Tags: android

I have in mind a simple alarm app for the purpose of hourly alerts/reminders. I intend to use it to remind myself to take a break from my computer at work. Basically an alarm to run in the background and perhaps a widget to provide a countdown to the next alarm.

I could easily find and download such an app, but the purpose of this exercise is to learn how to make my own apps.

I'm seeking advice for the way I should go about designing this app in order to keep it battery friendly. My experience in app design is very low, so any advice would be valued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For best battery life, use the AlarmManager class to queue a future event in a such a way that the phone is not prevented from sleeping in the meantime - if you tried to do it with an ordinary timer, you would have to hold a wakelock.

You can then make a widget that displays the remaining time, only when the phone is already awake.

If you want you can put a check box somewhere in the UI to enable a screen-on wakelock so that the user can see the countdown continuously, with a warning about the battery life impact.

Comment: This is very helpful as I'm still fairly inexperienced with the API. Probably wouldn't have found this one on my own. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Did you already read the [Articles on Optimizing Battery Life](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html) at android developers?
These provide the essential information that can help you keep battery consumption low.

Comment: I have not. I didn't even think to read this site... I'm the sort of guy who opens the box and learn by exploration rather than read the manual.